# JNI unsatisfied link error on ubuntu

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am using Java with Netbeans under Ubuntu. I am working with JNI and want to load the dll where in linux it has the ".so" extension. Why this piece of code is working:

```
static {
    System.load("/home/user/NetBeansProjects/JD2XX-DLL2/dist/jd2xx.so");
}
```

But this isn't:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("jd2xx");
}
```

with VM Options specified in netbeans to:

```
-Djava.library.path="/home/user/NetBeansProjects/JD2XX-DLL2/dist/"
```

I am getting an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
  no jd2xx.so in java.library.path
```

This works for me under Windows.

Comment: Doesn't `System.loadLibrary("jd2xx");` try to load libjd2xx.so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On a Unix system,

```
System.loadLibrary("Foo");
```

looks for a file called `libFoo.so` in the library search paths.

Rename the file accordingly.

By contrast, on a Windows system that call will look for a file called `Foo.dll` in the library search paths.